# Handling ggplot aesthetic that comes from two data sets but only display legend for one

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot both the raw data from `df_plotting` and the summary statistics from `table_max` (the mean values per conditon).

This is my code so far

Edit: Add `apa <- c("#68246d", "#a53d55", "#b87246", "#afa961")`

```
    ggplot(table_max, mapping= aes(x = phase_bins, y = Mean)) +
       geom_line(aes(group=as.numeric(cond_f),  
                     colour = cond_f), size = 1.2)+
       geom_line(df_plotting, mapping = aes(x=phase_bins, y = max_change_to_base, 
                     group=interaction(ID, cond_f), 
                     colour = cond_f, linetype =cond_f),
                     alpha = 0.3, size  =0.3)+
       geom_errorbar(table_max, mapping=aes(ymin=Mean-SD, ymax=Mean+SD, colour = cond_f),
                      width=.2, size = 0.7)+
       facet_wrap(factor(sample, levels = c("UGi", "UKi", "UKa"))~.)+
       labs(title="Max. temperature change by condition and sample", colour = "Condition:", linetype = "Condition:")+
       theme(guides(linetype=guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))+
       scale_x_discrete(labels= 
                              c("base", "stim1", "stim2", "recovery", "break"), drop = T)+
       scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-2,3))+
       scale_colour_manual(name = "Condition:",
                          labels = c("artificial", "cry", "laugh", "babble"), values=apa) +   
       scale_linetype_manual(name = "Condition:",
                         labels = c("artificial", "cry", "laugh", "babble"), 
                         values = c(1,2,3,4)) # also tried "solid", "dotted", "dashed", "twodashed"
```

The problem is, that this displays only solid lines for the legend, and I would like a combination of linetype and colour as one joint legend. I think this does not work because colour is assigned once to solid lines and then to the combination of linetype and colour and I can't override only one of the colour aesthetics.

Here is my data:

```
df_plotting

structure(list(ID = structure(c(35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L), .Label = c("UG201", 
"UG208", "UG209", "UG211", "UG215", "UG217", "UG219", "UG220", 
"UG221", "UG222", "UG228", "UG243", "UG247", "UG254", "UG268", 
"UG271", "UG272", "UG273", "UG274", "UG275", "UG280", "UG283", 
"UG284", "UG286", "UG297", "UG299", "UG308", "UG310", "UG315", 
"UG316", "UG330", "UG331", "UG334", "UG335", "UK103", "UK104", 
"UK105", "UK106", "UK107", "UK108", "UK110", "UK111", "UK112", 
"UK113", "UK115", "UK116", "UK117", "UK119", "UK122", "UK123", 
"UK130", "UK132", "UK135", "UK136", "UK138", "UK139", "UK140", 
"UK142", "UK145", "UK147", "UK150", "UK153", "UK155", "UK156", 
"UK159", "UK160", "UK162", "UK164", "UKA102", "UKA103", "UKA104", 
"UKA105", "UKA106", "UKA107", "UKA108", "UKA109", "UKA110", "UKA111", 
"UKA112", "UKA113", "UKA114", "UKA115", "UKA116", "UKA117", "UKA119", 
"UKA120", "UKA121", "UKA122"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("f", "m"), class = "factor"), trial = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
    cond_f = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("artificial", 
    "cry", "laugh", "babble"), class = "factor"), stimulus = structure(c(16L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L, 12L), .Label = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "b1", 
    "b2", "b3", "b4", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "l1", "l2", "l3", 
    "l4"), class = "factor"), phase_bins = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("pre", "baseline", "stim_bin1", "stim_bin2", 
    "recovery", "break"), class = "factor"), mean_change_to_base = c(0, 
    -0.516666666666667, -0.0333333333333336, 0.433333333333333, 
    0), max_change_to_base = c(0, -0.933333333333334, 0.166666666666668, 
    0.566666666666666, 0), sample = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("UGi", "UKi", "UKa"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), groups = structure(list(ID = structure(c(35L, 35L), .Label = c("UG201", 
"UG208", "UG209", "UG211", "UG215", "UG217", "UG219", "UG220", 
"UG221", "UG222", "UG228", "UG243", "UG247", "UG254", "UG268", 
"UG271", "UG272", "UG273", "UG274", "UG275", "UG280", "UG283", 
"UG284", "UG286", "UG297", "UG299", "UG308", "UG310", "UG315", 
"UG316", "UG330", "UG331", "UG334", "UG335", "UK103", "UK104", 
"UK105", "UK106", "UK107", "UK108", "UK110", "UK111", "UK112", 
"UK113", "UK115", "UK116", "UK117", "UK119", "UK122", "UK123", 
"UK130", "UK132", "UK135", "UK136", "UK138", "UK139", "UK140", 
"UK142", "UK145", "UK147", "UK150", "UK153", "UK155", "UK156", 
"UK159", "UK160", "UK162", "UK164", "UKA102", "UKA103", "UKA104", 
"UKA105", "UKA106", "UKA107", "UKA108", "UKA109", "UKA110", "UKA111", 
"UKA112", "UKA113", "UKA114", "UKA115", "UKA116", "UKA117", "UKA119", 
"UKA120", "UKA121", "UKA122"), class = "factor"), trial = structure(1:2, .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), cond_f = structure(3:2, .Label = c("artificial", 
"cry", "laugh", "babble"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:4, 5L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


table_max

structure(list(cond_f = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("artificial", 
"cry", "laugh", "babble"), class = "factor"), phase_bins = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("pre", "baseline", "stim_bin1", "stim_bin2", 
"recovery", "break"), class = "factor"), sample = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("UGi", "UKi", "UKa"), class = "factor"), 
    Mean = c(0, 0, 0, 0.244444444444444, 0.711111111111109), 
    SD = c(0, 0, 0, 0.760260897979524, 0.474268442504406), Min. = c(0, 
    0, 0, -0.899999999999999, 0.133333333333333), Max. = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1.8, 1.4), count = c(12L, 9L, 20L, 12L, 9L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), groups = structure(list(cond_f = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = c("artificial", 
"cry", "laugh", "babble"), class = "factor"), phase_bins = structure(2:3, .Label = c("pre", 
"baseline", "stim_bin1", "stim_bin2", "recovery", "break"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:3, 4:5), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thanks for any ideas on how to fix this!

Comment: Where is `apa` in your data?

Comment: Try to put `colour = cond_f, linetype =cond_f` in the original call to `gggplot., aes(.))` and remove them from both `geom_line` calls.

Comment: @Quinten apa is just four specified colours that I chose, I thought I had deleted all the irrelevant information, but must have forgotten that one. Sorry

Comment: @RuiBarradas I did try, but this creates the problem that then the lines from `table_max` (the overall mean) also has different linetypes, which makes the plot very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `cond_f`'s factor levels. Note that I define both the vector of colors `apa` and the vector of line types `lty`. And assign names to each of these colors and line types from the factor `cond_f` levels.
First the plot without the `scale_*`'s.

```r
library(ggplot2)

apa <- c("#68246d", "#a53d55", "#b87246", "#afa961")
apa <- setNames(apa, levels(df_plotting$cond_f))
lty <- c("solid", "dotted", "dashed", "twodash")
lty <- setNames(lty, levels(df_plotting$cond_f))

p <- ggplot(table_max, mapping= aes(x = phase_bins, y = Mean, 
                                    group = cond_f, colour = cond_f,
                                    linetype = cond_f)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.2) +
  geom_line(
    data = df_plotting, 
    mapping = aes(x = phase_bins, y = max_change_to_base, 
                  group = interaction(ID, cond_f),
                  colour = cond_f,
                  linetype = cond_f),
    alpha = 0.3, size = 0.3,
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_errorbar(
    mapping = aes(ymin = Mean - SD, ymax = Mean + SD),
    width = 0.2, 
    size = 0.7
  )
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Now the problem. The default `drop = TRUE` drops the unused factor levels, set it to `FALSE` on both `scale_colour_manual` and `scale_linetype_manual`.

```r
p2 <- p + 
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels = c("base", "stim1", "stim2", "recovery", "break"),
    drop = TRUE
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-2, 3)) +
  scale_colour_manual(
    name = "Condition:",
    labels = c("artificial", "cry", "laugh", "babble"), 
    values = apa,
    drop = FALSE
  ) +   
  scale_linetype_manual(
    name = "Condition:",
    labels = c("artificial", "cry", "laugh", "babble"), 
    values = lty,
    drop = FALSE
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Max. temperature change by condition and sample",
    colour = "Condition:", 
    linetype = "Condition:"
  ) +
  facet_wrap(sample ~ .) 

p2
#> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust
#> the group aesthetic?
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I don't believe this makes a difference.

```
p2 + guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. For some reason, this still displayed all groups as solid lines in the legend. I can't really figure out why

Comment: @clarulatta_elphadora Code corrected, see if it solves the problem now.